# Show message when Ajax function succeeds

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I would like to display a message when an `Ajax` function has succeeded but being new to `Ajax` I am struggling

```
function save_pos_reasons()
  {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "save_pos_reasons.php",
    data: $('#add_positioning').serialize(),
    success: function() {
       $("#successMessage").show();
        }
    });
 }


<div id="successMessage"> It worked </div>
```

At the moment this does nothing although the actual function is working

Comment: Looks OK to me. Are you hiding `#successMessage` by default with CSS? When you say the function is working, does that mean that the success function fires or just that the ajax call fires? Maybe your ajax call is failing.

Comment: no, there is no css attributed to the message, perhpas thats where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message div needs to be hidden by default, otherwise `.show()` will not do anything if it's already visible.

CSS:

```
#successMessage {
    display:none;
}
```

Or inline:

```
<div id="successMessage" style="display:none;"> It worked </div>
```

Comment: Can't believe I over looked the CSS, was too busy working about the Javacsript, worked great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code .  Only if the ajax is working the message will be displayed

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "save_pos_reasons.php",
        data: $('#add_positioning').serialize(),
        success: function() {
           $("#successMessage").html("It worked");
            }
        });
```

the html

```
<div id="successMessage"> </div>
```

Hope this helps. Thank you